# When temporarily banning someone from reviewing, give access to the misjudged content

Tags: feature-request, review, ban

**Issue**: Apparently I got a temporary review ban. It seems like I should have recommended an answer for deletion instead of saying that it looked good. I would like to read again the answer I had misjudged to understand where my decision failed. However it seems like I cannot access the now deleted answer.

**Feature request**: when temporarily banning someone from reviewing, give access to the content that have been misjudged so that the user can learn from it.

---

My ban:

[image]

My inability to learn from it as I cannot access the deleted answer:

[image]

Comment: Screenshot for ya: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cfFEM.png

Comment: @mhlester Thanks (I guess I misclicked this time)! I should stop reviewing when sobering up.